# Problems WITH THEME Android 5.0+

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes

I have a problem with my holo theme, it works right until Android 4.4 but when i run the same app in Android 5.0+ the dropdown menu for overflow items in the actionbar show the TEXT in color Black, i need the color WHITE

ANY IDEAS?

```
<style name="Theme.Flux" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_flux</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Flux</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Flux</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Flux</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Flux</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Flux</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_flux</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_flux</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Flux</item>

            <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Flux.Widget</item>

    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Flux" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_flux</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_flux</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_flux</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Flux</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleColor</item>
</style>

<style name="TitleColor" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Flux" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_flux</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Flux</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Flux" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_flux</item>  
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Flux" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_flux</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Flux" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_flux</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Flux" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_flux</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_flux</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_flux</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Flux" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_flux</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Flux" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_flux</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Flux.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Flux</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Flux</item>
</style>

<style name="menu_labels_style">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_label_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Use Theme.AppCompat instead of Theme.Holo

Comment: with appcompat i will loose the actionbar and i need it cuz this app is done with actionbar instead of toolbar, it is a lot of work to make the migration

Answer (score 0):

Change the style file also in values-v11 and values-v14 folders

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem when i put my style file in values-v11 and values-v14 folders i also add this style to my main style.

```
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
```

this is my style

```
    <style name="Theme.Flux" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_flux</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Flux</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Flux</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Flux</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Flux</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Flux</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_flux</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_flux</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Flux</item>

            <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Flux.Widget</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```